# Displaying some selectable strings in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text

My problem is I want to implement a GUI screen which will show some Strings. A shown string can be selected. Like Task Manager in Windows. However I could not find what that is. Here is a picture of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use swing, JList might help. Please check [JList Example](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jlist-class-example).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) and [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Swing you can achieve the same using user selectable [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

You should refer the [User selection example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)